# AudioSource Unity долгая прогрузка

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио

На AudioSource висит музыка, включается при старте и повторяется без. 2 мегабайта весом, 2 минуты продолжительностью. Загрузка сцены с этой музыкой занимает 5-7 секунд, а когда убираешь эту музыку из AudioSource - грузится мгновенно. Никакого кода даже, просто AudioSource с музыкой грузится долго а без неё мгновенно. Кроме нее на AudioSource ничего не висит. Вопрос то в следующем - как убрать эту долгую загрузку?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать решить эту проблему 2 вариантами

1. Загружать музыку динамически с помощью скрипта уже после загрузки сцены
2. Перекодировать музыкальный файл в другой формат. Например для того, чтобы воспроизвести .mp3 файл в игре, необходимо сначала его декодировать, а только затем воспроизвести. За счет этого самого кодирования файлы .mp3 будут весить меньше, чем некоторые другие форматы. Например .ogg будет весить намного больше, но его не нужно распаковывать, поэтому он сразу при загрузке в память готов к воспроизведению. Например в случае если для звука используется OpenAL данное решение помогает наверняка. Скорее всего Unity использует именно OpenAL, поэтому должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

А можно поставить loadInBackground(загружает в фоне) или перейти на версию 5.6 где весь звук теперь в другом потоке и loadInBackgtound теперь deprecated.